# Flask cache with redis

Tags: flask, redis, hashset, flask-cache, flask-caching

I need to cache the modules using Redis and each module cache data need to be in separate hash table. Let me say, I have 2 modules:

1. employee
2. company
   Now the API's related to employee module need to be cached in the hash table employee. For example:

```
hset('employee', 'emp_id_2', 'emp_name_2')
hset('employee', 'emp_id_1', 'emp_name_1')
```

When I integrate the redis cache in flask, I could see there is no hget and hset. How do I store the data with hash in redis?

The rediscache integration in flask

```
rediscache = Cache(app, config={
        "CACHE_TYPE": "RedisCache", 
        "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": "127.0.0.1", 
        "port": 6379
    })
```